# How to access json from one liquid file in another liquid file

Tags: javascript, json, liquid

Simplified version of my problem. vars.liquid needs to be a separate liquid file.

vars.liquid:

```
<script>
  var config = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  };
</script>
```

main.liquid:

```
  {%- render 'vars' -%}
  <script>
    var config = '{{ vars.config | json }}';
  </script>
```

var config is returning null

Answer (score 0):

The variable `config` returns null when accessed via main.liquid because you are using Liquid to retrieve the variable. However, please note that config was declared with javascript. To access it successfully, you need to retrieve it through JavaScript as well.

main.liquid

```
 {%- render 'vars' -%}
  <script>
    // you should be able to directly call `config` inside your script tag here since it was already declared as a javascript variable.
    console.log('config json', config);
  </script>
```